# Degree in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

A graph with p vertices and q edges, the sum of the degrees of all p vertices is $2*q$.

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why.

Answer (score 1):

Because each edge has two ends.

Answer (score 1):

The degree of a vertex represents the number of edges connected to it. So the summation over all the degrees actually counts all the edges **twice**, because each edge has two endpoints and a summation over all the degrees, runs over all the nodes, including both endpoints of the edge.